# Allocate maximum memory available

Tags: algorithm, memory, memory-leaks, malloc

I currently try to write a programm which is supposed to allocate the maximum memory available. I came to a solution which limits the area of potential available memory until both borders are equal (see listing)

```cpp
void enforceMemoryLeakage(void** arrayOfAllocMemory)
{
    unsigned int maxMemory = 0x80000000;
    unsigned int minMemory = 0x50000000;
    unsigned int attempAllocatedMemory = minMemory + (maxMemory - minMemory) / 2;
    void* pAllocMemory;

    while((maxMemory - minMemory) > 1)
    {
        pAllocMemory = malloc(attempAllocatedMemory);

        if (pAllocMemory != NULL)
        {
            minMemory = attempAllocatedMemory;
            attempAllocatedMemory += (maxMemory - minMemory) / 2;
            free(pAllocMemory);
        }
        else
        {
            maxMemory = attempAllocatedMemory;
            attempAllocatedMemory = minMemory + (maxMemory - minMemory) / 2;
        }
    }
    arrayOfAllocMemory[0] = malloc(maxMemory);
    void* pAllocAdditionalMemory = malloc(100);

    if (pAllocAdditionalMemory == NULL)
        std::cout << "Maximum memory: " << minMemory << "\n";
}
```

The above displayed code works fine. However if the command is executed

```cpp
void* pAllocAdditionalMemory = malloc(100);

if (pAllocAdditionalMemory == NULL)
    std::cout << "Maximum memory: " << minMemory << "\n";
```

I would have expected that there is no further memory available. However it does not work which brings me to my actual question why the above shown approach does not work.

Best regards

Ratbald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify OS nor platform so I am completely guessing here so read with extreme prejudice...

Assuming you do not have a bug in your binary search code... My bet is you face **memory fragmentation** problems as you are successfully allocate/free memory during execution other processes can do the same so you might fragment your memory. Example:

1. OS has 2 MByte chunk of continuous free memory
2. you allocate 1.5 MByte of mem (`0.5 MByte` free)
3. some other process allocates 1 KByte (`0.499 MByte` free)
4. you free the 1 MByte (`1.0 + 0.499 MByte` free two fragments)
5. and attempt to allocate 1.25 MByte
   but OS does not have 1.25 memory in single continuous chunk so it failed hence you allocate the 1MByte again (`0.499 MByte` free)
6. you succesffuly allocate 1 KByte (`0.498 MByte` free)

Depending on the OS memory management strategies you could sometimes even not need another process interfering to fragment memory ...

There are however **another possibilities not related to Fragmentation**. In case of emulations or WOW64 the OS will not allocate whole available RAM, also there are limits on single continuous chunk size. For example Win32 will not allow more than ~1.25 GByte but that does not mean there is only 1.25 GByte of free RAM ...

Comment: I'm really grateful for your detailed answer. For the sake of completeness I'd like to mention that I´m developing a Windows x86 application. My initial intention was to enforce a memory leakage which is required by a following test. However this test is only successful if there is no further memory available. Is there another simple way to enforce a memory leakage by requesting an additional byte through the malloc command  and return a NULL pointer?

Comment: @RatbaldMeyer memory leak is just repeating (in loop/event/thread) of: allocating memory and not releasing it which decrease free memory over time up to a point where no free RAM is left ...  so simply allocate 100 Bytes in some thread loop with some sleep or in timer which will steadily diminish free memory over time... btw on Windows there is: [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-globalmemorystatusex) but hard to say how it works in case of WOW64 (32bit app on 64bit OS)